# Can I create a filter that prevents sending certain emails?

Tags: gmail-filters

How can I create a subject line or body text filter that filters outgoing email?

When the filter matches a message, the message should not be sent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to _prevent_ sending an email that matches a specific filter?

Answer (score 2):

Filters are something that happen when an email is *received*, not sent - so what you ask for isn't possible with Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you are looking for, consider the Gmail Labs "delayed send" option. It gives you at the very least a short "undo" window.